# Update one table row data depending on another table data count Parse

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I have this two tables in parse.

First Table  : `ProductID | ProductName | LikesCount`

Second Table : `ID | ProductID | CustomerID`

I want to update the `LikesCount` row dynamically when ever i update SecondTable.

`LikesCount` row need to contain Total Count of ProductIDs that in Second table .
Then i can get the total count of likes to each `ProductID`

im doing this from my iOS app. when someone click like button it updates SecondTable and then it update the FirstTable with count

Let me know if you are unclear

Comment: I would use an `afterSave` cloud code method

Comment: @Paulw11 can you give reference link to check. i dont know about it

Comment: https://parse.com/docs/js/guide